# Insert attribute in a <html> line

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I wan to insert this line of code:

```
xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"
```

to this line of code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

so the output is like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
```

I'm using this: [Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

when use this:

```
$html->find('html', 0)->outertext = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" > ';
```

The whole HTML file will be lost and will be replaced by the code above. It's getting all the outertext of HTML.
But I just want to change the line of HTML code.

Comment: The content is lost because you change the `outertext` which (probably) includes the dom-objects contents as well.

Comment: The doc on your lib is here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access I’m not sure it can add attributes with namespace; in fact, I don’t think so. Attributes are accessed as object attributes thus limited to attribute names, and PHP does not allow `:` in there AFAIK. Did you consider not using the lib (for this)? Would that be an option?

Comment: I consider to not to use this lib..any suggestion how to do this? @Kissaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, using Simple DOM Parser:

```
$content = $html->find('html', 0);
$content->outertext = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">'.$content->innertext().'</html>';
```

Comment: The result is not successful, it displays  only.